# Winsock client not connecting to any server

Tags: c, windows, sockets, network-programming, port

I made two separate C programs using Visual Studio 2022, A client application and a server application, but my client app cannot connect to any external servers, including google.com. My server works and listens for incoming traffic on FTP port 20. My router settings also allows incoming traffic on port 20. Maybe it doesn't work because I am using both the client and server program on the same machine?

```
C:\Users\aaaaaaa>netstat -an | find ":20"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:20             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

My server is listening on port 20 of my host machine. Currently I am just testing to make sure my client connects to my server, and then I will start sending data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define PORT 20

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET serverSocket, clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    int clientAddrLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    char buffer[1024];

    // Initialize Winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create socket
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating socket\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up server address structure
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind socket
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error binding socket\n");
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Listen for incoming connections
    if (listen(serverSocket, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error listening\n");
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Server listening on port %d...\n", PORT);

    // Accept connection
    clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientAddrLen);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting connection\n");
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Convert client's IP address to string
    char clientIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(clientAddr.sin_addr), clientIP, INET_ADDRSTRLEN) == NULL) {
        perror("inet_ntop");
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", clientIP, ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port));

    // Receive data
    int bytesRead = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        // Process the received data as needed
        FILE* file = fopen("received_data.bin", "ab");
        if (file != NULL) {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, file);
            fclose(file);
        }
    }

    // Close sockets
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    closesocket(serverSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#define SERVER_IP "137.186.208.160"
#define PORT 20
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int isServerOnline() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    // Initialize Winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed\n");
        return 0;  // Server is considered offline if WSAStartup fails
    }

    // Create socket
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating socket\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;  // Server is considered offline if socket creation fails
    }

    // Set up server address structure
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER_IP, &(serverAddr.sin_addr));
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Attempt to connect to the server
    if (connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == 0) {
        printf("Server at %s:%d is online.\n", SERVER_IP, PORT);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;  // Server is online
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to the server. Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        printf("Server at %s:%d is offline.\n", SERVER_IP, PORT);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;  // Server is offline
    }
}

int main() {
    while (1) {
        int result = isServerOnline();

        Sleep(5000);  // Sleep for 5 seconds before checking again
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I used ping previously in my code to ping my ip address but it lost all sent packets.

Comment: You have some good error checking in the code. Is any of it being triggered on either side?

Comment: 1. What error did you get? 2. There is nothing here that sends anything to anybody. 3. You have some *missing* error checking in the `recv()` part. If `bytesRead < 0` you need to call `perror()` and close the socket, and if it is zero you must close the socket.

Comment: My bad, i wrote my title wrong. I meant that my client cannot connect to any external server. My server works fine and does not throw any errors, but my client says failed to connect to server, error 10061. There is no problem with my server code, its just my client code cannot reach any server at all, even when i tried google.com's port 80.

Comment: That is `connection refused`: nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. If `137.186.208.160` is an external IP address you need to arrange port forwarding from your router. Or else use the server's internal IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to help you, but sockets interface comes from Berkeley software for unix, and in unix, the result of system calls is -1 in case of failure, so, please check the value of the constants `INVALID_SOCKET` or `SOCKET_ERROR` (which I have never seen before) and if thay are not `-1`, then change `INVALID_SOCKET`, and `SOCKET_ERROR` to `-1`, or `< 0`, and do error processing that way (this is the unix way, sorry, but as in The Mandalorian TV series, "That is the correct way!")

One possible reason of the failure is that socket binding to ports under 1024 is forbidden for unprivileged user processes (this is, nonroot users in unix systems) and I don't know exactly how this functionality is mapped in windows systems (probably non SYSTEM or Administrator accounts are not capable of binding to ports under 1024)  Or change your port number to e.g. 2000.  And probably this problem will disappear.

I've spoken! :)

Note: I cannot test your code here, as I have no windows machine available to run your test.